# Python: Using Multiprocess to switch functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn about multiprocessing in python.

What I want to happen is have x increase with time, then when I hit 'enter' it will decrease with time and I can keep hitting enter to switch from increasing to decreasing.

All i've managed to make so far is this

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return (x+1)
def f1(x):
    return (x-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    x=0
    while x<100:
        x = pool.apply_async(f, [10])
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

I'm having trouble looking though the documentation because they don't give explicit examples.
Please help I have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threw together an example to give you some ideas.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from threading import Thread

NUM_PROCESSES = 4

def consumer(q):
    out = []
    while True:
        val = q.get()
        if val is None:
            #poison pill
            break
        #doing some work here
        time.sleep(0.01)
        out.append(val)
    return out

def producer(queue):
    flip = True
    val = 5

    def flipper():
        nonlocal flip
        input('enter to flip it!')
        while True:
            flip = not flip
            txt = 'up' if flip else 'down'
            input('val is {}, now counting {}'.format(val, txt))

    t = Thread(target=flipper, args=(), daemon=True)
    t.start()

    while val > 0:
        for _ in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
            queue.put(val)
        val = val + (1 if flip else -1)
        time.sleep(0.2)

    print()
    print('hit zero, shutting down.')

    for _ in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
        #poison pills
        queue.put(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=NUM_PROCESSES)
    m = Manager() # N.B.: multiprocessing.Queue doesn't work with Pool.apply_async
    q = m.Queue()

    results = pool.apply_async(consumer, args=(q,))
    producer(q) # running in main thread because I'm lazy

    print(results.get())
```

output:

```
ben@nixbox:~$ python3 multithread.py 
enter to flip it!
val is 13, now counting down
val is 4, now counting up
val is 8, now counting down
hit zero, shutting down.
[5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The way your original code was set up, parallelizing didn't make a whole lot of sense.  So I switched to a producer/consumer paradigm: your producer produces "work units" that increase until you hit enter, then decrease until it hits zero, then it loads up the work queue with poison pills that tell the consumers to shut down.  There's a few tricks to get the input/flipping thing to work, but I'll just let you look at the code for that.  Note that I used *threads* to wait on blocking I/O operations and *processes* to do (simulated) CPU-heavy work.  This is on purpose.

There are lots of ways to structure multiprocessing code but I find producer/consumer to be a very useful pattern.  One thing you really don't want to be doing is rapidly creating processes to do a teeny tiny amount of work and then tearing them down.  This is **slow**!  (I will note that using `Pool` correctly avoids this - it keeps its workers alive for you.  Still, worth mentioning since a lot of people start out by firing off a bunch of `Process`es in a loop, then later wonder why their parallel code is slower than their single-threaded code :-))

Comment: I have *NEVER* seen the `nonlocal` keyword before. I had no idea it existed.

Comment: Yeah it's a python 3 thing.  In python 2 you have to make `flip` a 1-element list so you can mutate it within the closure.  Ugly!

Comment: one question: why do you use `multiprocessing.Manager.Queue` rather than `queue.Queue`? Any reason? I've never really played with `multiprocessing` before and have just make thread pools

Comment: @AdamSmith Good question.  `apply_async` barfs when given a normal `Queue` - don't ask me why.  I'll look into it and update the answer if I get some time.

Comment: Great answer regardless. My usual design is `resultq = queue.Queue(); workq = queue.Queue();` `def do_work(workq, resultq): resultq.put(perform_work(workq.get()))` `def make_work(workq): workq.put(create_work)`, `for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS): t = Thread(target=do_work, args=(workq, resultq), daemon=True); t.start()` `while JOBS_TO_BE_DONE: make_work(workq)`

Comment: Oh, looked in to it.  `Pool` uses an internal `Queue` to dispatch data to its pooled workers - and you cannot put a `Queue` inside a `Queue`.  This seems like an unfortunate limitation but nothing can be done about it short of completely rewriting `Pool` to not use an internal queue.

Comment: Or re-write `queue.Queue` to be able to hold `queue.Queue`s :)

Comment: @AdamSmith `queue.Queue` isn't process-safe. It's just a wrapper around a `collections.deque`, which knows nothing about inter-process communication. Normally you would use a `multiprocessing.Queue` instead, but that isn't picklable (because it contains an unpicklable `multiprocessing.Lock`), so you can't pass it to any of the `multiprocessing.Pool` instance methods. You could pass a `multiprocessing.Queue` to all the workers in the `Pool` using the `initializer`/`initargs` argument to the `Pool` constructor, or just stick with the `multiprocessing.Manager.Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a great way to test `multiprocessing`. You're doing an operation to `x` that can't really effectively be parralellized - you only want one process to be able to increment `x` at a time. Otherwise, different workers will stomp on the values of x being set by other workers. And, since all your workers are doing is incrementing x, they're basically going to need to run completely sequentially, with no concurrency at all.

That said, for this code to work properly, you need to actually fetch the real result from the [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object returned by `apply_async`:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return (x+1)
def f1(x1):
    return (x-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    x=0
    while x<100:
        x = pool.apply_async(f, [x]).get()  # Added get, changed 10 to x
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Adding the `get` call will make the main process block until the worker has actually completed. Of course, this means you're not really doing anything in parrallel, but that's really the only way to increment the variable safely.